# Can you download a file from Amazon S3 bucket without having AWS login credentials

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a problem statement wherein I wish to download the file in using Express and NodeJS Framework.

Can I download the file from amazon/s3 bucket without having a login account in AWS ?

Comment: Sure you can, if the file is public or you have S3 pre-signed url for it.

Comment: ok Mr. Marcin. Thank you for your time and assistance. I will try. regards

Comment: And what about upload @Marcin?

Comment: You can also create s3 pr-signed files for upload. I can provide more info in the answer with some links, if this would address your issue?

Comment: @Marcin. Yes please . I will be very thankful. regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are **three common** ways of accessing S3 objects/files without the need for AWS credentials:

1. Granting **public access** to the bucket, a folder in the bucket or [individual objects](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/). This is probably the easiest to setup and use, but your objects are, well, public.
2. Use [S3 pre-signed url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-presigned-url.html) url. These are **temporary** urls that your backend would have to generate for the front-end to use. The urls can be for downloading or uploading files. Anyone with these urls can download/upload files to your bucket, but since urls are temporary, [hot-linking](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/7606/hotlinking) the urls is limited.
3. Front your bucket with [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/). This allows to keep your bucket fully private, and all your files will be accessed through CloudFront **edge locations**, which can also speedup your website.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will definitely try.regards

Comment: @SuchetaShrivastava No problem. Glad could help.

Comment: Looks like OP is running code on AWS server, in which way they should be using IAM Role, and no login account is necessary!

Answer (score 2):

```
aws s3 ls --no-sign-request s3://"YOUR BUCKET NAME"/
```

Then

```
aws s3 cp s3://" YOURBUCKETNAME "/ . --recursive --no-sign-request
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: A better option might be: `aws s3 sync --no-sign-request s3:://your-buck-name /local/path`. In this way, aws cli can auto sync and do version control, also no need to use `--recursive` flag.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue.

```
var S3 = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3');
var fs = require('fs');
const stream = require('stream');
const request = require('request');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const awsS3 = new AWS.S3()
 
var app = express();

app.use(cors());

var AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID =  'AKIA....';
var AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY =  'uQ/l....';
var S3_BUCKET_NAME = 'realindia';
var toUploadFileName = 'abcd.pdf'

app.get('/downloadURL', (req,res,next) => {
  const s3 = new S3({
    apiVersion: '2021-04-10',
    accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
    region: 'us-east-2' // region of my bucket and what it says is expected
  });

  var s3params = {'Bucket': S3_BUCKET_NAME, 'Key': fileName }
  
  s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', s3params, function(err, url) {
    if (err) res.json(err);

//To download the File.

    var options = {
        Bucket : s3params.Bucket,
        Key    : s3params.Key
    };

    res.attachment(s3params.Key);
    var fileStream = s3.getObject(options).createReadStream();
    fileStream.pipe(res);
  });
});
```

Comment: that's a *very bad* way... you should never hardcode credentials in your code. If this code runs on AWS instance - you should use IAM Role, and no credentials are necessary.

Comment: Hi felix, I have no official or formal AWS credentials. Using pre-signed URL. regards